# The use of "、" in more than three items

Tags: mandarin, conjunction

In the following sentence:

> **沙溢、胡可与安吉、小鱼儿**一家四口集体亮相，同时《捉妖记2》视效制片人Ellen Poon也透露了电影幕后制作的花絮。

I think the use of "、" should be A、B、C与D. In other words, it should be put between each word except the last one, in which case 与 or 和 (etc...) should be used instead.

However in this sentence, it is in the form of A、B与C、D, so now I wonder what is the correct form, and whether there is any difference on the meaning regarding how you put the "、" to concatenate words.

Comment: *沙溢、胡可与安吉、小鱼儿一家四口集体亮相* is bad writing. It doesn't make sense in any case.

Comment: @dan So how do you write?

Comment: 沙溢、胡可与安吉、小鱼儿，set up two groups. 一家四口 is one group. They can't put it together. You can say 沙溢、胡可与安吉、小鱼儿进行比赛。It means 沙溢、胡可 vs 安吉、小鱼儿. You can also say 一家四口沙溢、胡可、安吉与小鱼儿集体亮相。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the reason why it is put in this way, as through a search, you will find that 沙溢、胡可 are the parents and 安吉、小鱼儿 are the children in the family.

As far as I know, the "correct" form is A、B、C与D. But it may not the only acceptable way, especially when you can divide the words into groups. Like in this one, parents and children. The four words are not equivalent now, and "与" is used between groups but not between the words.

Answer (score 2):

Balance.

My Chinese teacher taught me when I was a pupil. And that is written in the appendix of each Chinese dictionary for pupil.

“沙溢、胡可与安吉、小鱼儿” is balanceable.

“沙溢、胡可、安吉与小鱼儿” is not balanceable.

Take 与/或 as the equilibrium point, please.

If there were odd items, tried to find equilibrium point to get balance approximately. Like, “A、B、C 与/或 D、E” or “A、B 与/或 C、D、E”. Otherwise, never use 与/或.